# Why is Euler's totient function equal to (p-1)(q-1) when N=pq and p and q are prime?

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, arithmetic, totient-function

Why is Euler's totient function equal to $(p-1)(q-1)$ when $N=pq$ and $p$ and $q$ are prime?
I had my own proof for it but I really don't like it (it feels not intuitive at all because it requires factoring!) and I feel there must be a more direct way to do it by a different counting argument.

If anyone has one it would be greatly appreciated!

My "proof":

Recall:

$\phi(N) = $ the number of elements that are relatively prime to $n$ (i.e. have a mod inverse)

$N = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime.

Let's count the number of elements between $1$ and $N-1$ that are NOT relatively prime to $p$ and $1$. Those elements must have at least $p$ or $q$ as one of its factors. So let include all number that have $p$ as a factor and $q$ as a factor and are in the given range. Thus:
$$0p, 1p, 2p, ..., kp, ..., p(q-1)$$
and
$$0q,1q,2q,...,jp,...,q(p-1)$$

That gives a count of:
$$N - p - q + 1 = pq - p - q + 1 = (p -1)(q-1)$$

QED as required.

The reason I am not happy with this argument is that it seems to me there should be a clear intuitive way of doing it without having to factor or substitute the definition of N. This seems clear because multiplying $(p-1)$ by $(q-1)$ seems to be a very cute formula and it I would be surprise that its a coincidence because $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$ also have clear interpretations.

Comment: Given that in general, $\phi(n)=n\cdot \prod_{p:p|n} (1-\frac1p)$ (which is a nice exercise to prove using the inclusion-exclusion principle), you can see that the function has a very close relation to the prime factors of $N$. Thus, it is not surprising that a proof would use the factoring of $N$.

Comment: Also, since $\phi(n)$ is the number of positive integers less than $n$ that are relatively prime to it, it makes some sense that factoring is involved. Otherwise, how are you going to determine whether another number is relatively prime to $n$?

Comment: While there are obvious applications of this result to cryptography, this question is about a mathematical proof and is not directly relevant to computer science. Therefore I am migrating it to [math.se].

Comment: There's something missing in your proof: if you just put the two lists together, you're counting the multiples of $pq$ twice. Which is where the $+1$ in $N-p-q+1$ comes from. Beyond that, this seems a perfectly reasonable proof strategy to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a grid representing all integers mod $pq$.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&q&2q&\cdots&(p-1)q\\
p&p+q&p+2q&\cdots&p+(p-1)q\\
2p&2p+q&2p+2q&\cdots&2p+(p-1)q\\
\vdots&\vdots&\\
(q-1)p&(q-1)p+q&(q-1)p+2q&\cdots&(q-1)p+(p-1)q\\
\end{array}$$

You can confirm that there is no double representation here by considering what $mp+nq\equiv\hat{m}p+\hat{n}q$ would imply.

Now note that the top row and left column are precisely the numbers in the table that are not relativelty prime to $pq$.  The rest is a $(p-1)\times(q-1)$ rectangle, consisting of the values that *are* relatively prime to $pq$.